# Angular JsTree with custom json data

Tags: angularjs, jstree

I want to add a custom `icon` and `subtext` in a node in [ngJsTree](https://github.com/ezraroi/ngJsTree), like this sample.

[image]

```
{
    'id': 1,
    'text': 'a text',
    'icon': "icon",
    'icon2': 'newIcon',
    'subtext': 'new text'
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom data by using the `li_attr` node attribute, it worked for me. It also keeps the custom data when you drag and drop your nodes.

In your case, your node would be:

```
{
 'id': 1,
 'text': 'a text',
 'icon': 'icon',
 'li_attr': {'icon2': 'newIncon', 'subtext': 'new text'} 
}
```

Regards.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I use this? (to show `icon2` for example)

Comment: I don't use `html` structure of jstree, I use: `#category-tree(js-tree="treeConfig" ng-model="category" tree="treeInstance")` in angularjs